# Проект для портфолио

Tags: java, spring

Здравствуйте. Изучаю Java, написал достаточное количество лабораторных, так что с Java SE проблем нет. Решил попробовать написать что-то используя Spring и написал обычный CRUD, используя Spring Boot + JPA. Можете посоветовать тему какого-нибудь проекта, чтобы расширить свои знания по Spring и было бы здорово, если бы посоветовали источники для изучения т.к. я потерялся в куче информации, которая иногда протеворечит друг-другу. Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй усложнять своё приложение. Для ясности напиши его на Spring MVC, подключи Spring Security авторизация и регистрация, используй hibernate.

Comment: это я делал. вот взять hibernate-ok, подключил. дальше нужно данные с бд подтягивать, посмотрел в сторону JPA, поюзал, понял, что мало функционала, начал использовать jpql и встает вопрос, зачем юзать и то, и то одновременно, если jpql больше возможностей дает, но тогда почему jpa популярен? значит, я делаю что-то не так.
и вот таких вопросов просто масса возникает. Поэтому было бы неплохо, если бы мне посоветовали какой-нить проект с минимальной дорожной картой